# c# opening a compress file into a program

Tags: c#, registry, contextmenu

I have a program which compress a certain file and save as an *.pld extension. My question would be like this. How to access my own extension file and read the content of this file. Thus somebody help me on how to read and display this file into my main form which contains a datagridview by double clicking the file?I use 
[registry key helper](http://codinggrapes.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/registry-helper-library-in-c) to put my context menu after having making an installer on my program. When I start compressing a file, saving it and open the file, it was just opening my application again and again.

How to solve that one?.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to read the args from the main method. E.g:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 form = new Form1(args);
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

args will contain the full path of the double clicked file